# how to print json format to console using bean

Tags: java, spring-integration

I am transforming object to json with spring integration.

```
<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter query="SELECT * FROM posts" row-mapper="postMapper"
                                      channel="dataInbound" data-source="dataSource">
        <int:poller fixed-rate="5000" />
    </int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <int:channel id="dataInbound" />

    <int:object-to-json-transformer input-channel="dataInbound" output-channel="printing"/>
    <int:service-activator id="printing" method="print"
                           input-channel="print" ref="eventActivator"/>
 <bean id="postMapper" class="com.example.domain.PostsMapper"/>

    <bean id="eventActivator" class="com.example.Dispatcher"/>
public class Posts {

    private String id;
    private String title;
    private String author;
   ...Constructor and setters/getters...
}

public class PostsMapper implements RowMapper<Posts> {

    public Posts mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException{
        String id = rs.getString("id");
        String title = rs.getString("title");
        String author = rs.getString("author");
        return new Posts(id, title, author);
    }
}
```

But how do I print transformer into console `<int:service-activator>`.
Well I tryed this but it didnt work:

```
 public void print(List<Posts> posts){
        for (Posts post: posts){
            System.out.print("\n***** " + post);
        }
    }
```

Errors I am getting:

```
Failed to convert from type [java.util.ArrayList<?>] to type [java.util.List<com.example.domain.Posts>] for value '[{id=1, title=test, author=me}]'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.util.LinkedHashMap<?, ?>] to type [com.example.domain.Posts]
No converter found capable of converting from type [java.util.LinkedHashMap<?, ?>] to type [com.example.domain.Posts]
Problem invoking method: public void com.example.Dispatcher.print(java.util.List)
```

So how my `bean` should look like for printing it to console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, read stack traces carefully.. Your problem is not related to the printing to console. You are not close there.

See that error one more time:

```
No converter found capable of converting from type [java.util.LinkedHashMap<?, ?>] to type [com.example.domain.Posts]
```

So, your `payload` is really not a `List<Posts>` it is an `ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<?, ?>>` in the end.

Not sure how though. The `<int:object-to-json-transformer>` creates a `string` representation for JSON by default. You probably do something else not showing in the question...

**UPDATE**

To fix your immediate problem you just need to have your `print()` like this:

```
public void print(List<Map<?, ?>> posts){
```

However according your `List<Posts>`, it's fully not clear why would one convert the `List<Posts>` result from the `<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>` to JSON, since he/she doesn't expect JSON downstream.

Comment: Well I edited my question. Added all the errors I dont know if it helps.